# Connection server is not making request token call to OAuth2.0 provider server

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I implemented OAuth 2.0 Provider layer so all communication between my server and 
IBM-Connections server  happens with proper OAuth token.
I followed the steps mention in below mention URL:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/dx/Building_Embedded_Experience_gadgets_for_third-_party_IBM_Connections_Activity_Streams

Request is coming to my server (after clicking on the gadget mention on above URL) 
https://?client_id=853e738c8f514ea0b0beb03c538df1e4&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FBLTCon4Gold1.actiance.local%3A9444%2Fconnections%2Fopensocial%2Fgadgets%2Foauth2callback&response_type=code&scope=read_stream%2Cpublish_stream&state=WcSdxX0BvPkwiOli2VFnlsIWEWzAprpT6DW2I9RXEjDtUpD-faNVQkYvLb1AcgX3Z3njZg0qPPZjd5XMT7ENQSYiBr1thpOiUlLzYKkmt5-2qG304QgYEpWE8csezSIJ-4qHiFFeGbJpILbgzUw7DBoNMVMPcF-OfMbZ5orqgKwBCCajFVKdgQeukivSq4r3hBFY89lgto4co_dacDR1Dt7AWDM

After user credential validation, OAuth provider layer is redirecting the request to call back URL with code and state as query parameter:
https://bltcon4gold1.actiance.local:9444/connections/opensocial/gadgets/oauth2callback?code=477885dfb80644958cd4bae049bc2b9f&state=WcSdxX0BvPkwiOli2VFnlsIWEWzAprpT6DW2I9RXEjDtUpD-faNVQkYvLb1AcgX3Z3njZg0qPPZjd5XMT7ENQSYiBr1thpOiUlLzYKkmt5-2qG304QgYEpWE8csezSIJ-4qHiFFeGbJpILbgzUw7DBoNMVMPcF-OfMbZ5orqgKwBCCajFVKdgQeukivSq4r3hBFY89lgto4co_dacDR1Dt7AWDM

Response shows http status code 200.
But the Problem is IBM-Connection server is not making further call for request Token. 
Please advise me.

Comment: I am trying to understand the problem better.  Are you using a gadget being rendered in Connections to call web services protected by OAuth?  If so what version of OAuth are you using from Connections.  Connections is only an OAuth 2.0 client.

Comment: Yes i am using OAuth 2.0

Comment: Which OAuth provider are you making a request to?

Answer (score 0):

check your systemout.log for PXIX or other SSL errors

if you are using a self signed certificate, you should import the key into the trust store.

Login to your Deployment Manager
Go to Security > SSL certificate and key management
Click on Key stores and certificates
Select CellDefaultTrustStore
Click Signer Certificates
Click Retrieve from port
Give it a name localhttp
type in the ip:port 
click retrieve from port

you can also turn on trace in your deployment manager